# Deploying to on prem IIS from self hosted devops agent

Tags: iis, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, self-hosting

I am trying to setup an azure devops release pipeline to deploy to an on prem IIS server via a self hosted agent (also on prem).  I’m not sure exactly where the agent should be installed.

I tried installing the agent on a different machine and running the pipeline but got the error - cannot find appcmd.exe.

Is it a requirement that the agent live on that IIS server, or can it live on a separate machine? is there some trickery involved in configuring my pipeline so it can deploy to a iis on another server?

Comment: This is a rather tricky question right now. There are tons of ways to automate web app deployment to IIS, and calling `appcmd` on the same machine is just one of them. So, the question to you is which ways of deployment do you want to go? If local `appcmd` is preferred, then likely the build agent should be installed on the same machine.

Comment: I guess that could be part of my confusion - if there are tons of ways to do this… what are some other ways?  Should I be concerned about installing the agent right on the IIS server, or is that normal an ok?  Thank you for responding! :)

Comment: Is usually install IIS app pools and sites through a central build agent using powershell remoting. Just another example of what's possible.